# Ошибка: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, визуализация

Есть [DataFrame](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nhM0qnMKoSVgsVt4akNWnZvWArZT7dJ0/view?usp=sharing), строю график

```
courses_grow_month_index = courses_grow.pivot_table(index='month_start')
courses_grow_month_index.plot(figsize=(16, 8), grid=True)

plt.tight_layout()
```

всё ок, понимает даты, не ругается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда пытаюсь построить несколько графиков, ругается как будто у меня не все данные типа `datetime`.

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(8, 24))
spec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=1, nrows=len(courses_grow_month_index.columns), figure=fig)
sn = 0

for i in courses_grow_month_index.columns:
    ax = fig.add_subplot(spec[sn, 0])
    ax.plot(courses_grow_month_index[i])    
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    ax.set_title(i)
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.set_xlabel("Дата")
    ax.set_ylabel("Прирост")
    sn+=1
```

> ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units

Comment: а что говорит `courses_grow_month_index.info()`?

Comment: @strawdog 

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
PeriodIndex: 41 entries, 2016-03 to 2019-07
Freq: M`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

замените:

```
ax.plot(courses_grow_month_index[i])
```

на:

```
ax.plot(courses_grow_month_index.index, courses_grow_month_index[i])
```

или замените на:

```
courses_grow_month_index[i].plot(ax=ax)
```

---

**UPD:** если коротко, то функция `ax.plot()` умеет работать с двумя типами параметров:

1. два первых параметра - списки значений по оси `X` и по оси `Y`
2. передаем только один список значений - `y`, тогда значения по оси `X` подставятся автоматически - `0 ... N-1`

Из документации

```
>>> plot(x, y)        # plot x and y using default line style and color
>>> plot(x, y, 'bo')  # plot x and y using blue circle markers
>>> plot(y)           # plot y using x as index array 0..N-1
>>> plot(y, 'r+')     # ditto, but with red plusses
```

---

Если же использовать метод Pandas - `Series.plot(ax=ax)`, то в качестве значений по оси `X` будут использоваться значения индекса последовательности `Series`, а в качестве значений по оси `Y` - сами значения `Series`. Кроме того указав параметр  `ax=ax` мы явно указываем в каком `subplot` мы хоти рисовать.

Comment: С первым вариантом ту же ошибку выдаёт, а вот второй сработал. Если ещё объясните на словах, что произошло, буду признателен)

Comment: @МихаилБойко, дополнил ответ

Comment: спасибо, понятно